# SQL query that may be a subquery question or an inner join

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have a homework assignment that asks:

"For each customer whose total sales amount is greater than $250, list customer ID, customer name, and total sales amount of the customer. Give descriptive names for all computed fields."

Normally, I would never come to S.O. for homework answers, as I would just push through and figure it out, but this one seems to have me stuck.

This is my incorrect query to the question:

```
    SELECT customerid
    FROM customer
    WHERE customerid In (SELECT sum(untipricesold) AS totalSales 
    FROM orderline WHERE sum(orderline.unitpricesold) > 250)
    GROUP by customerid;
```

The result I got is:
"group function is not allowed here".

I have attached a screenshot of the relevant tables that SHOULD be used for this question. Again, this isn't something I would usually do and am completely against cheating for school, but please help.

[image]

Comment: Try moving your Where to a Having clause.

Answer (score 3):

You need `HAVING` clause when you are come with filtration after aggregation or groping :

So, i would inclined with `JOIN` :

```
SELECT c.customerid , c.customername, o.TotalSales  
FROM customer c INNER JOIN
     (SELECT customerid, SUM(untipricesold) AS TotalSales  
      FROM orderline O
      GROUP by customerid 
      HAVING SUM(untipricesold) > 250
     ) o
     ON o.customerid = c.customerid;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a `HAVING` clause.  Also, you probably want to be selecting the `customerid` in the subquery, rather than the sum, since you are comparing to `customerid` in the outer query.

```
SELECT customerid
FROM customer
WHERE customerid IN (SELECT customerid FROM orderline
                     GROUP by customerid HAVING SUM(untipricesold) > 250);
```